# How to make a head model of any person?

Tags: modeling

I need a way that will quickly create a mesh based on a face photo (and possibly a profile portrait)
There are a lot of videos on the Internet about a paid addon. It works well, but it's still paid. I also know that you can use scanning, but I don't think that it is possible to create a mesh from one photo using scanning, this is too little.

Comment: you can use free softwares like Meshroom but it needs a lot of pictures to build a 3D mesh

Comment: It depends on the quality you're after. What will you use it for ?

Comment: @Gorgious , i want to use them for printing. if the quality is rough, then I can improve them in sculpting anyway